# how to solve console log issue in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting data from an API and initially when console it in `fetchData` function it works but when console it in `fetchDailyData` function and call this function in another component it didn't work.

How can I solve this issue?

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const url = `https://covid19.mathdro.id/api`;

export const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const { data: { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate }} = await axios.get(url);
    return { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate };
  } catch (error) {

  }
}

export const fetchDailyData = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/daily`);
    console.log(data); // <<==>> chrome browser is not showing this console log
                       // fetchDailyData function called in another component
  } catch (error) {

  }
}
```

Calling `fetchDailyData` function in another component
when I call `console.log`, I can't see the data in console of my browser

```js
const Chart = () => {
  const [dailyData, setDailyData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchApi = async () => {
      setDailyData(await fetchDailyData());
    }
    console.log(dailyData);
    fetchApi();
  });
};
```

Comment: Js statements must be within swirly brackets - {}

Comment: If the console is not showing the `console.log` statement you have highlighted, it's almost certainly because the code before it is throwing an error - try examining the error in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

`https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily` which is your url in `fetchDailyData` doesn't return any data currently at all.

I suppose you have to check if this backend still available. And it is a good practice to check the response status (normally it should return statusCode 200) in response callback.